# Write in a part of a document the current time?

Tags: command-line, text-processing

How can you write the current time from terminal in a document? In a specific place of the document, I mean.

Comment: There are many ways to do this but your question is too vague. Where in the document you want to write it ? What kind of a document is it ?

Comment: Is the document a text file, or a `.doc`?  Do you just want the time right now, or do you want it to update later?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the file is a text file and you want the current date and time appended on its own line to the end of the file, use:

```
date >> myfilename
```

(If that doesn't handle your use case, [**edit your post**](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/275798/edit) to clarify your question.)

Answer (score 0):

If you'd just like to append it to the end of the document (I am going to assume it is a simple text file) then it's quite simple:

```
echo `date` >> myfile
```

This will, however, print a full date and time stamp, like `Mon Apr 11 21:25:28 SAST 2016`. If you want just time, you can use this:

```
echo `date +%T` >> myfile
```

This will give you output in an H:M:S format, like this: `21:27:36`

Comment: Why are you using `echo` and command substitution instead of just redirecting the output of `date` directly?  `date +%T >> myfile`

Comment: Valid question. A bad habit that stems from me often storing the output of command substitution in variables and echoing the variable elsewhere in a script.

Answer (score 0):

Since you ask for insertion into a **specific place** of the document, first define the "specific place" by a unique string. I've chosen the string `##TIME##` for the following example file:

```
this is some text
Insert time here: ##TIME## <-- the time
this is some text
```

This `sed` command will insert the current time at the position marked by `##TIME##`:

```
sed -i'.bak' 's/##TIME##/'"$(date +%r)"'/g' file
```

Result:

```
this is some text
Insert time here: 09:37:05 PM <-- the time
this is some text
```